# Angular Schema Form - Check if form is validated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm using angular-schema-form (http://schemaform.io) to create forms in an angular app.

In the form definition I created a button like this with an onClick event.

```
{
    "type": "button",
    "title": "Save",
    "onClick": submitFunc
}
```

javascript code:

```
function submitFunc($event, form) {
    //I want to check if the form is valid
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');
    if (form.$valid) {
        console.log('valid');
    }
}
```

I want to check if the form is valid but it doesn't work. I found that it's not working because the `form` object passed to the function is not the form but the field.

Anybody knows how to check if the form is validated here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your onClick function to pass the form.  For example, if your form was defined as follows :

```
<form name="myForm">
.... Your form
</form>
```

Your form definition would look like this :

```
{
  "type": "button",
  "title": "Save",
  "onClick": "submitFunc(myForm)"
}
```

Also your handler wont recieve an $event object anymore, so it would be defined like this :

```
function submitFunc(form) { ... }
```